# how to generate PGP key revoke in java and Bouncy Castle

Tags: java, bouncycastle, pgp

I want to generate revocation certificate together with public and private key pair generation.

Private and Public key generated correctly.

I tried to do like this:

```
public void generateRevoke(String id, PGPPublicKey pk, PGPSecretKey secretKey, char[] passPhrase, OutputStream out) throws PGPException, IOException {

    PGPSignatureGenerator signatureGenerator = new PGPSignatureGenerator(
            new JcaPGPContentSignerBuilder(secretKey.getPublicKey().getAlgorithm(), PGPUtil.SHA1));

    PGPPrivateKey pgpPrivKey = secretKey.extractPrivateKey(
            new JcePBESecretKeyDecryptorBuilder().setProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider())
                    .build(passPhrase));

    signatureGenerator.init(PGPSignature.KEY_REVOCATION, pgpPrivKey);

    PGPSignature signature = signatureGenerator.generateCertification(id, pk);

    PGPPublicKey key = PGPPublicKey.addCertification(pk, id, signature);

    key.encode(new ArmoredOutputStream(out));
}
```

but in output file I got PGP MESSAGE not PGP PUBLIC KEY

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I solve problem. Correct method return public key with revocation cert inside:

```
public void generateRevoke(String id, PGPSecretKey secretKey, char[] passPhrase, OutputStream out) throws PGPException, IOException {

    PGPPublicKey oldKey = secretKey.getPublicKey();

    PGPPrivateKey pgpPrivKey = secretKey.extractPrivateKey(
            new JcePBESecretKeyDecryptorBuilder().setProvider( provider )
                    .build(passPhrase));

    PGPSignatureGenerator signatureGenerator = new PGPSignatureGenerator(
            new JcaPGPContentSignerBuilder( secretKey.getPublicKey().getAlgorithm(), PGPUtil.SHA1 ) );

    signatureGenerator.init( PGPSignature.CERTIFICATION_REVOCATION, pgpPrivKey );

    PGPSignature signature = signatureGenerator.generateCertification(id, oldKey);

    PGPPublicKey newKey = PGPPublicKey.addCertification(oldKey, id, signature);

    out = new ArmoredOutputStream(out);

    newKey.encode(out);
    out.close();
}
```